# Dotted Line between h2 span

Tags: css, html

I have been trying to get some dotted lines all over my site.
I'm starting to understand the idea but I ran into another problem...
I am making another dotted line, this time between text and an image. This one's a bit different.

I am also getting problems where sometimes the image goes under the lines due to the width changes: when I update my site, etc.

How can I make it here so that I can have the dotted lines' width change to the total width of the h2?
I want the dotted lines not to bother anything and just go smooth through it.

This is the code I'm using, and I need to keep it in the basic principle:

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

      $('.serviceDesc').hide();
      $('.serviceName:first').addClass('active').next().show(); 

      $('.serviceName').click(function(){
      if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) { 
      $('.serviceName').removeClass('active').next().slideUp(); 
      $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(); 
      }
      return false; 
      });

      });
      </script>
      <style>
      #servicesContainer {
          width: 485px;
          height: 400px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          margin-top: 20px;
      }
      h2.serviceName {
          margin: 0;
          margin-bottom: 5px;
          margin-top: 5px;
          background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/IcnZl.png);
          background-position: right top;
          background-repeat:no-repeat;
          height: 29px;
          line-height: 24px;
          width: 480px;
          font-size: 18px;
          font-weight: bold;
          float: left;
          color:#000;
      }
      h2.serviceName a {
          color: #000;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: block;
      }
      h2.active {
          background-position: right bottom;
      }
      .serviceDesc {
          margin: 0 0 10px;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          width: 480px;
          clear: both;
      }
      .serviceDesc .block {
      }
      .serviceDesc .block p {
          color: #413f44;
          margin: 0;
          font-size:18px;
      }
      </style>

      <div id="servicesContainer">
        <h2 class="serviceName"><a href="#">Text...............................................................................</a></h2>
        <div class="serviceDesc">
          <div class="block">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud. </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="serviceName"><a href="#">Text...............................................................................</a></h2>
        <div class="serviceDesc">
          <div class="block">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="serviceName"><a href="#">Text...............................................................................</a></h2>
        <div class="serviceDesc">
          <div class="block">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.<br />
              <br />
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="serviceName"><a href="#">Text...............................................................................</a></h2>
        <div class="serviceDesc">
          <div class="block">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="serviceName"><a href="#">Text...............................................................................</a></h2>
        <div class="serviceDesc">
          <div class="block">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud. </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="serviceName"><a href="#">Text...............................................................................<br />
          </a></h2>
        <div class="serviceDesc">
          <div class="block">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud. </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="serviceName"><a href="#">Text...............................................................................</a></h2>
        <div class="serviceDesc">
          <div class="block">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="serviceName"><a href="#">Text...............................................................................</a></h2>
        <div class="serviceDesc">
          <div class="block">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K7MHK/

Comment: Basically instead of writing out the .......... i want it to just be 100% until the image. how can i do it in this situation? I already figured out the other situations but not in here.

Comment: You need to provide a better code sample, based on your comments to the existing answer.

Comment: I will add the rest maybe it will help

Comment: I added the entire code to show my problem

Comment: I also updated the link here http://jsfiddle.net/K7MHK/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with the [phone/email question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588757/expanding-dots-pushing-link-or-text-down/7588840#7588840), it's the same idea.  You can use a background image on the element to create the dotted lines.  Since you've already got a background on the `<h2>`, add it to the `<a>`:

```
h2.serviceName a {
    background: url(dots.gif) repeat-x bottom left;
    /* Other CSS styles */
}
```

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nr5Kg/).  As a bonus, it means you can get rid of all your hard coded dots too.

*Update:* If you want to block the dots from behind the words, add a `<span>` element with solid background color that wraps the text:

**HTML**

```
<h2>
    <a href="">
        <span>Juicy text</span>
    </a>
</h2>
```

**CSS**

```
a span {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

This will prevent the dotted background of the `<a>` from showing through.

Comment: Oh i forgot to mention i have a background image there that wont go with any color haha crap.. uhm i need to think this otu

Comment: @mystycs You can set *both image and colour for background*: `background: red url(images/person.png) no-repeat top left;`

Answer (score 2):

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/dwCmg/7/)

```
h2.serviceName {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: relative;
    height: 29px;
    line-height: 24px;
    width: 480px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    color:#000;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
h2.serviceName a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

h2.serviceName a:after {
    content : "";
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    z-index: -1;
}
h2.serviceName a:before {
    content : "";
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/IcnZl.png);
    width: 30px;
    height: 29px;
    float: right;
}
```

It's a little hacky and you can still kinda see the dots on the right... but it gives you a little better idea the power of CSS3

Comment: +1 I like the :before/:after pseudo elements better than my `span`.  Made me think of this guy's work: http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/demo/backgrounds.html

Comment: I added the entire code to show what im talking about i tried using your idea but the dots didnt show still.